# FFmpeg CRF causing glitches on fade-ins

Tags: ffmpeg, transitions

I'm transcoding some high bitrate h264 5K videos which start with a fade in, at CRF 22 H264 mp4 using FFmpeg via MyFFmpeg. The fade ins are all causing some blocky glitching for a few frames. It's not visible on my powerful pc but played back on a Meta Quest 3, I'm seeing them every time. The videos are otherwise perfect - are there any settings I can tweak to maintain quality during this fade in, whilst not having to significantly increase file size throughout the whole video? Thanks for the advice.